# Converting values in a dictionary to individual lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do i convert the values in a dictionary to individual lists?

For example:

```
dictionary = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6],'c':[8,9,10]}
```

outcome:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [8,9,10]
```

So far i could only think of creating individual lists and putting it into the list.

Is there any looping or better ways to do this?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Instead of ```a```, you can use ```dict["a"]``` to access the same list

Comment: Thats redundant what you are trying to do , you already have the required values , instead of using it as a list notation use it via a dict notation dict['key']

Comment: That's what i'm currently doing, but as i have many data (lets say 500), i'm wondering if there's any better way to do this as i have to create an individual list for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

a dictionary has keys and values, you can create a list out of keys and values by using `d.keys()` and `d.values()` respectively. if you want to only have value for one key say `a` you can use `d["a"]`, and it gives you `[1,2,3]`.

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6],'c':[8,9,10]}
a = d["a"]
b = d["b"]
c = d["c"]
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d.keys())
print(d.values())
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import __main__

d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6],'c':[8,9,10]}

for k in d.keys():
    __main__.__dict__[str(k)] = d[k]

print(a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6],'c':[8,9,10]}

for s in d.keys():
    vars()[s] = d[s]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Result

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[8, 9, 10]
```

**Update** According to OP's comment to another answer he wants "exact output" as in the question. This is also easy. Changing the second loop to

```
for s in d.keys():
    print(s + ' = ', end='')
    print(vars()[s])
```

we get the output

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [8, 9, 10]
```